# laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException when do POST on online server

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I have got MethodNotAllowedHttpException when running on online server, but on local server it runs well.

The PHP version is same, the method is used POST.
The other POST methods are runs well except this one.

on blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('update.product') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal js-form">
```

on routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/updateProduct', [
   'uses' => 'AdminController@updateProducts',
   'as' => 'update.product'
]);
```

**Update:**

After I changed the route into 'get'

```
Route::get('/updateProduct', [
   'uses' => 'AdminController@updateProducts',
   'as' => 'update.product'
]);
```

it reach the updateProducts function.

but of course there is no data to process. So, why my post method form sent the get method? and on the browser developer tools I've got POST?

**but on my local server it runs well** only on online server I've got this issue.

[browser dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Savth.jpg)

Comment: check is there any method with similar name `update.product`

Comment: Check any cache permission to write. This error is common caused by No route match.

Comment: What do your browser developer tools show? Is the POST really happening, and to the right URL? Does the form include any [method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing)?

Comment: hi @Shibon , there is no method with similiar name

Comment: hi @daremachine , how can I check the cache permission to write?

Comment: hi @Don'tPanic , I've got POST request_method and to the right URL '/updateProduct' on the browser developer tools, and the form doesn't include any method spoofing

Comment: I usually see this error if the form method doesn't match the route method or I'm not sending a csrf token.

Comment: Can you try changing the form method as "post" instead of "POST" case sensitive

Comment: This might seem silly, but you _do_ have @csrf inside your form tags, correct?

Comment: @MattC yes, the form sending GET instead of POST request, but still don't know why

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati it doesn't help

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane yes I do have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs due to a missing  module extension PDO database on the server, so upload file into the application will throws error.

Installing the module extension will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using different method if you use laravel collective.
`{!! Form::open(['url' => 'client/store','method'=>'post','id'=>'client-register']) !!}`

and in route it must be

`Route::post('client/store', 'ClientController@store')>name('client.store')`.

or you can write your action

```
action="{{URL::to('client/store')}}"
```

At first see if routes are define properly.

And also you can try clearing the cache using artisan command.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. Do you mean config:clear ? actually I have try cache:clear and config:clear but it doesn't help. I think the routes are define properly, since it runs well on my local server